# Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT) Localization Problems (MakePRI)

Tags: c#, localization, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a question regrading the localization of WinRT-Apps.
As far as I know the system works like that:

Strings || Resources

- de-DE

  - Resources.resw
- en-US

  - Resources.resw
- etc.

  - Resources.resw

So far, this folder structure is implemented in my project.
In my ***Package.appxmanifest*** the **"Default Language"** is set to **"en-US"**, so everything should be okay from my point of view, if language is not supported it should fall back to "en-US", since it's set there.
But if I compile the stuff, in the Output-Box from VS I get a warning from MakePRI

```
2>MakePRI : warning 0xdef01051: No default or neutral resource given for 'Resources/String'. The application may throw an exception for certain user configurations when retrieving the resources.
```

I searched so far and found only things that are related to the Advertising SDK from MS, which I don't use in my project, so the problem shouldn't be there.

Why is MakePRI giving me this message, where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that you have a localized string named "String" which is not defined in your default "en-US\Resources.resw" file.
If you look in your "de-DE\Resources.resw" file you should find the entry. You will have to report it to the default file or delete it if it is not needed.

All the strings which exist in your non-default localization files must have a default value in the default language file.

Comment: Thanks. Found the "String"-Key in the "ja-JP\Resources.resw". I just copied the whole resources stuff from my old Silverlight App, which I'm now porting to WinRT. Haven't looked into theses files for a long time. ^^

Answer (score 2):

Just for the records: I had the same warning when building a Windows 8.1 Store Universal App (Windows + Windows Phone). My project contains a folder with images which are used as pinpoint markers on a map. The folder names were

- Assets/marker/yes/foo.png
- Assets/marker/yes/bar.png
- Assets/marker/yes/baz.png
- ...
- Assets/marker/no/foo.png
- Assets/marker/no/bar.png
- Assets/marker/no/baz.png
- ...

The separation in yes/no subfolders is appliation-specific. My program uses markers inidicating the presence/absence of something on a map.

For each element under Assets/marker I got twice the warning below - one for the Windows project and the other for the Windows Phone project.

> MakePRI : warning 0xdef01051: No default or neutral resource given for ...

According to the [MakerPRI documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj552947.aspx) the resource indexing system tries to recognize language identifiers in folder and file names. I figured that the reason for the warning was the folder name "no". MakerPRI interpreted it as "Norwegian" and rightfully complaint that my project contains resources which are available in one language but not for all languages.

I changed the folder name "no" to something else and the warnings were gone. So bottomline is that one should **be careful with file names and folder names which could be misinterpreted as language tags**. Here is a [list of all available language tags](http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry).

Comment: i think it is impossible to be careful with file names and folder name...I have similar case but my file name is compIt.png where it think "It" is a language, it is really hard to avoid it. Do you have other solution except changing the file name?